# NDSolve does not satisfy initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations

For the problem I'm facing, I have three coupled diff eqns that I'm trying to solve

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
i = 4;
R2 = 0.001;
RL = 100000;
RS = 100000000;
R1 = 0.04834;
C1 = 8.48;
C2 = 3.44;
s = NDSolve[{V1[t] == RS/(RS + R1)*V2[t] + RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), 
   V2'[t] == 
    1/C1*(i R2 RL RS - (R2 RL + R1 (R2 + RL) + (R2 + RL) RS) V2[t] + 
      RL (R1 + RS) V3[t])/(R2 RL (R1 + RS)), 
   V3'[t] == 1/C2*(V2[t] - V3[t])/R2, V2[0] == 0, 
   V1[0] == RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), V3[0] == 0}, V1, {t, 0, 5}]
```

I set `V1[0]==RS*R1*i/(RS + R1)` which actually equals aprrox `0.19`, but when i plot `V1[t]` the intercept is `~0.12`.

Comment: When I run your code, I get a solution where V1[0] = 0.19336 (evaluate `V1[0] /. First[s]`.)  This shows the same way on the graph.  Can you provide a copy of your output?  Knowing which Mathematica version and operating system you're using might also be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I found that the issue was because of carry over variables. I closed mathematica and copied the code in and now the results are fine. How can I avoid this in the future. I thought that ClearAll["Global`*"] would prevent this

Answer (score 5):

This system can be solved exactly with `DSolve`

```
$Version
```

> "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
i = 4;
R2 = 0.001 // Rationalize;
RL = 100000;
RS = 100000000;
R1 = 0.04834 // Rationalize;
C1 = 8.48 // Rationalize;
C2 = 3.44 // Rationalize;

s = DSolve[{V1[t] == RS/(RS + R1)*V2[t] + RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), 
     V2'[t] == 
      1/C1*(i R2 RL RS - (R2 RL + R1 (R2 + RL) + (R2 + RL) RS) V2[t] + 
          RL (R1 + RS) V3[t])/(R2 RL (R1 + RS)), 
     V3'[t] == 1/C2*(V2[t] - V3[t])/R2, V2[0] == 0, 
     V1[0] == RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), V3[0] == 0}, {V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]}, t][[1]];

V1[t] /. s /. t -> 0.
```

> 0.19336

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[{V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]} /. s],
 {t, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Green, Thick}, {Red, AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]}},
 PlotLegends -> {V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]}]
```

[image]

For t >= 0, V2 and V3 are very close to each other.

```
NMaximize[{Norm[V2[t] - V3[t]] /. s, t >= 0}, t]
```

> {0.00115436, {t -> 0.0485123}}

Comment: Wow thanks for the plot as well!

Comment: For future reference, what is the benefit of using rationalize and what exactly does /. do in the code? I've only been using /. because i saw it in the mathematica sample.

Comment: To get information about a function or operator, highlight (double-click) and then press `F1` (Help) for documentation.

Comment: @jerry Exact solvers love exact coefficients.